# What does ph stand for in reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm reading the OpenAI baselines code for DQN.

There's a function named `make_obs_ph` that `take a name and creates a placeholder of input with that name`.

What does `ph` stand for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning there is placeholder.

place, holder. ph.

Comment: oh yeah haha why didn't I think of that!

Comment: Can you select it as answer rather than just upvoting? It's a 25 point difference.

Comment: Sorry SO requires a few minutes to pass before I can accept an answer. Maybe you can help me with this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252741/openai-baselines-why-simultaneously-use-tf-stop-gradient-and-specify-var-lis