# OpenAI baselines: Why simultaneously use `tf.stop_gradient` and specify `var_list`?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, openai-gym

In OpenAI baselines code on [DQN](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/simple.py), `tf.stop_gradient` is used on the q values of the target network during building the operation graph to prevent the contributions of the target q values to the minimization of the loss. (line 213)

However, when calling `minimize`, the `var_list` is specified as only the `tf.Variable` with scope that falls under the q network being optimized, excluding the variables with scope under the target q network. (line 223)

I'm not sure why they do both. The two approaches seem to achieve the same result.

Comment: I suggest the other Stack Exchange site https://datascience.stackexchange.com which is more active around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's redundant. IMO code reads better - you know that gradient will not flow through that expression, and also you know exactly which variables will be affected.

One would indeed suffice to achieve equivalent effect.